# JavaScript API Function Name Best Practices

Tags: javascript, oop, object, setter

Which one is the preferred way to increase a value in a API.

```
.setX(val,increase){
    if(increase) this.x += val;
    else this.x = val;
}
.increaseX(val){
    this.x += val;
}   
.incrementX(val){
    this.x += val;
}   
.addX(val){
    this.x += val;
}
```

Comment: Definitely go with `add(val)`...

Comment: `increment` typically means "increase by one" (or at least, by one "step" which is fixed), so it would not take the amount as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a "preferred" way to increase a value that I am aware of but a good rule of thumb is

1. to be as true to the intent of the function in the function name as
   possible.
2. To write functions that only do one thing

For instance this function:

```
.setX(val,increase){
    if(increase) this.x += val;
    else this.x = val;
}
```

Does two separate actions and would be better served by splitting into 2 separate functions `setX(val)` and maybe `increaseXByVal(val)`

Of the names you provided it appears that `increaseX` comes closest to the true intention of the function but is not clear what you are increasing it by or that it requires a parameter. This could be cleared up by using the name I provided but that is really a matter of preference.

The problem with `addX` is that it implies that you will be adding x to the supplied number and then returning that value. Instead what you are doing is really `addingValueToX` which leaves no confusion